# Testing conditions set by around_action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, minitest

In a Rails app the current locale ist set in `ApplicationController` through a `around_action` callback. This is a cleaner solution than using only a `before_action` which would leave the request specific locale hanging around.

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  around_action :with_locale

  def with_locale
    I18n.with_locale(find_current_locale) { yield }
  end
end
```

Since the current locale is reset after the request finished its not so easy to access the request specific locale in a test. With a `before_filter` the following test would pass:

```rb
it 'sets locale from request'
  get :action, locale: locale
  I18n.locale.should == locale
end
```

I cannot think of a way to implement this test to work with an `around_filter` without injecting some additional logic into the controller. Is there a simpler way with RSpec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about checking if `I18n.with_locale` has been called with proper parameters.

```
it 'sets locale from request'
  allow(I18n).to receive(:with_locale)
  get :action, locale: locale
  expect(I18n).to have_received(:with_locale).with(locale)   
end
```